# SVG xlink:href always pulling image from the last record in a Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm using an image pulled from a user entry to fill an SVG element - i.e. staff portrait on a team page. Currently the image displayed is always from the last user entry in the (Wordpress) loop.

Here's the relevant part of my template:

```
foreach ( $allusers as $user ):

$image = get_field('headshot', $user );

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 221 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 221 300;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st4{fill:url(#img-<?php echo $user->ID; ?>);}
  </style>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img-<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image xlink:href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle class="st4" cx="110.5" cy="150.4" r="78.5"/>
</svg>
```

If I simply do a:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
```

This shows the correct image for each entry, so I'm assuming it's to do with the xlink:href part.

How can I get the correct image to show in the SVG element?